# Unable to find missing Feature from content DB

Tags: sharepoint-server, health-analyzer

I am resolving Missing Server Side Dependencies Error on SP 2013.
While Trying to resolve missing Feature Error, I tried to find the Feature from Content DB, but it didn't return any result.

`select * from Features where FeatureId in('MyFeatureID')`

Then I tried Powershell script

```
$featureID = "My FeatureID"
$siteID = "SideID"   

#Display site information

$site = Get-SPSite $siteID  
Write-Host "Checking Site:" $site.Url

#Remove the feature from all subsites
ForEach ($web in $Site.AllWebs)
    {
        If($web.Features[$featureID])
            {
                Write-Host "`nFound Feature $featureID in web:"$Web.Url"`nRemoving feature"
                $web.Features.Remove($featureID, $true)
            }
            else
            {
                Write-Host "`nDid not find feature $featureID in web:" $Web.Url
            }   
    }

#Remove the feature from the site collection
If ($Site.Features[$featureID])
    {
        Write-Host "`nFound feature $featureID in site:"$site.Url"`nRemoving Feature"
        $site.Features.Remove($featureID, $true)
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "Did not find feature $featureID in site:" $site.Url
    }
```

it did not work

Then I tried 
`stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id <id-of-feature-missing> -force` it didn't remove the message from Health Analyzer.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint 2016?

If you use SharePoint 2016, you should install the [August 2016 PU](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53399), because when you firstly deploy SharePoint Server 2016 this rule can generate false errors.

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Go to Central Administration->manage service applications->search service application-> Farm Search Administration->edit the page-> Make any change to a web part (e.g., change the title of a web part), and then undo->save the web part.
2. Go to Central Administration->manage service applications->search service application-> Search Administration->edit the page-> Make any change to a web part (e.g., change the title of a web part), and then undo->save the web part.
3. Go to Central Administration->Monitoring > Health Analyzer > Review problems and solutions->Click on the error ”Missing server side dependencies”->Click the “Re-analyze Now” button in the ribbon->Click Close-> Wait a minute or two->Click the error link again.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

[Missing server side dependencies (SharePoint Server).](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/technical-reference/missing-server-side-dependencies)

[SharePoint 2013 Health Analyzer: Missing Server Side Dependencies.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24495.sharepoint-2013-health-analyzer-missing-server-side-dependencies.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using SharePoint 2013. I tried changing Search web part Title as suggested, unfortunately, the problem still persists.